# docpad subdirectory rendered into general directory

Tags: docpad

How to move files from `src/documents/posts/post1.html` to `out/post1.html` without the subfolder `posts` appearing in the out directory?

I have a sub directory `posts` in my `documents`

```
src/
    documents/
        index.html
        contact.html
        posts/
            post1.html
            post2.html
```

And I want the posts to be in `out/post1.html` not `out/posts/post1.html`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out you can set the `relativePath` property to whatever you want

```
@getCollection("html").findAllLive(..).on 'add', (document) ->
    newRelativePath = document.get('relativePath').replace('posts/','')
    document.set('relativePath', newRelativePath)
```

---

**ImportantNote**:

if you use a `findAllLive` whith a selector that includes the `relativePath` and then change the `relativePath`, the document will be removed from the collection. Alternatively you can set another flag and use it for finding.

```
@getCollection("html").findAllLive({$or:{relativeOutDirPath:'posts', isPost: true}}).on 'add', (document) ->
    document.set('relativePath', newRelativePath)
            .setMeta({isPost: true})
```

Comment: Well done figuring it out. :) Don't forget to accept this answer as soon as StackOverflow allows you. ;)

Comment: I need to get collection of all the files from out directory or document directory. I tried @getCollection("html").findAllLive({relativeOutDirPath: '/'},[{order:1}]) but didnot work